# Cover the area evenly with certain number of points

Tags: python, math, points, poisson

I want to somehow generate points to evenly or pseudo-evenly cover the area (for example 0<X<100, -100<Y<0) with certain number of points N=500 (for example). I know only 2 ways how to realize it on Python: Poisson disc sampling, Halton sequence generation.
Poisson disc sampling allows to obtain well-quality even distribution, but it doesn't allow me to control the number of points. It depends on the radius of sphere r, and parameter k. No direct correlation with the points number. I used

```
poisson_disc.Bridson_sampling()
```

Halton sequence generation allow me to use N directly, but distribution not so good. I used

```
def generation(count, scale): 
    def halton(b):
        n, d = 0, 1
        while True:
            x = d - n
            if x == 1:
                n = 1
                d *= b
            else:
                y = d // b
                while x <= y:
                    y //= b
                n = (b + 1) * y - x
            yield n / d

    haltonx = halton(3)
    haltony = halton(2)
    xy = np.zeros((count, 2))
    for i in range(count):
        xy[i, 0] = next(haltonx) * scale
        xy[i, 1] = next(haltony) * (-scale)
    return xy
```

Do you know how to make the Halton distribution more evenly or how to control number of points in Poisson disc sampling? Maybe you can recommend some other methods for this task

Comment: Why not just generate random coords within the bounds of the area?

Answer (score 0):

As another method, why not draw both coordinates from a uniform distribution?

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
numPts = 500
xs = uniform.rvs(loc=0, scale=100, size=numPts)
ys = uniform.rvs(loc=-100, scale=100, size=numPts)
for x, y in zip(xs, ys): print(x, y)
```